# Нажатие на кнопку в overlay'е

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь сделать какой-никакой overlay для одной игры.

Получился такой код:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]

    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWind, int nIndex);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.Wheat;
        this.TransparencyKey = Color.Wheat;
        this.TopMost = true;

        int initialStyle = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20);
        SetWindowLong(this.Handle, -20, initialStyle | 0x80000 | 0x20);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

На выходе получаю вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но суть в том, что невозможно нажать на эту кнопку. Как сделать так, чтобы вся форма была "прозрачной для кликов", а именно в месте кнопки - нет? Чтобы можно было на неё нажать.

Comment: а почему вы решили что вы на нее не нажимаете? Попробуйте, сделать действие по нажатию например вывести сообщение!

Comment: @Monomax, пробовал, ничего не происходит. Она визуальная.